# splitting values in double quotes using c#

Tags: c#

I have text file with values like

```
"444","/5"," ", " "," john""66""88"
```

I want to get only values with double quotes
So I want seven strings as below after splitting

```
first = "444"
second = "/5"
third = " "
fourth =" "
fifth  = "john"
sixth= "66"
seven= "88"
```

`.Split("' '")` doesn't seem to work

Comment: _Any_ effort to solve your problem?

Comment: Aren't you splitting on commas instead of a space?..

Comment: Use a regex like this: "\"([^\\\"]*?)\""

Comment: No no thats what the difference is, I need values in double codes

Comment: I  new to c sharp please provide the complete regex expression, that would help

Comment: Also, you want to split on commas and remove the quotes from the result, but splitting will be very dangerous, if for some reason there is a comma inside the quoted text then your data will be corrupted.

Comment: I just edited my answer to reflect the fact, that the comma is not a separating character but more kind of garbage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex instead of splitting, if for some reason there is a comma inside the quoted text and you split by comma then your data will be corrupted.

Use this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("\"([^\"]*?)\"");

List<string> elements = new List<string>();

var matches = reg.Matches(theExpression);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    var theData = match.Groups[1].Value;
    elements.Add(theData);
}

//Now you have in elements a list with all 
//the values from the string properly splitted.
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I need and that comma doesn't matter I only want double codes thing

Comment: The code I posted will return exactly what you want, did you tried? I expanded a bit the example.

Comment: Also, the comma is important, if you have "Doe, John" per example  as value, splitting by comma will split it in two.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

I just found, that your parts might not be comma separated. Here is a char based approach:

```
string s = "\"444\",\"/5\",\" \", \" \",\" john\"\"66\"\"88\"";

var myParts = new List<string>();
int pos1 = s.IndexOf('"');
if (pos1 == -1)
    throw new Exception("No qoutes!");
int pos2 = s.IndexOf('"', pos1 + 1);
if (pos1 == -1)
    throw new Exception("No second quote!");

while (true) {
    myParts.Add(s.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 1));
    pos1 = s.IndexOf('"', pos2 + 1);
    if (pos1 == -1)
        break;
    pos2 = s.IndexOf('"', pos1 + 1);
    if (pos2 == -1)
        throw new Exception("No final closing quote!");
};
```

#### previous

You might try it like this

```
string s = "\"444\",\"/5\",\" \", \" \",\" john\"\"66\"\"88\"";
//Take away the leading and the final ", then split with the full "," -> These are your parts 
var parts = s.Trim().Substring(1,s.Length-2).Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//Now get them back as List, each wrapped in "part"
var qoutedParts = parts.Select(p => "\"" + p + "\"").ToList();
```